# Cannot format Instant while formatting DateTime using Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, date, datetime

In my Spring Boot app, I can easily format `LocalDate` and `LocalDateTime` with a global config:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "dd.MM.yyyy";
    private static final String DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss";

    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jsonCustomizer() {
        return builder -> {
            builder.simpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
            builder.serializers(new LocalDateSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMAT)));
            builder.serializers(new LocalDateTimeSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_TIME_FORMAT)));
        };
    }
}
```

Now I also need to format my `Instant` field in `DATE_TIME_FORMAT`, but could not find a proper parameters (the serializer method takes different parameters):

```
builder.serializers(new InstantSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_TIME_FORMAT)));
```

How can I format Instant as the other date formats above?

Comment: No, that would not make sense. For formatting with date and time you need to assume a time zone, and an `Instant` is independent of time zone. Try `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_TIME_FORMAT).withZone(yourPreferredZoneId)` (I haven’t tried it myself).

Comment: It does not make any sense and still displaying in the same format like `"2023-02-26T12:11:29.811883600Z"`. Any idea?

Comment: If you can, you may want to give us a [mre] to play around with?

Comment: SOrry, but I could not. It is just a config file and displaying message in Instant format would be enough if you can create a Spring project. Thanks in advance

Comment: Looked up in the library and I do not know why, but class InstantSerializer has only protected constructors. Currently, I can only recommend you manually add @JsonSerialize annotation to every Instant field

Comment: Thanks,  what about the `builder.serializers()` part? Should I add anything to there?

Comment: As sad here https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/issues/168#issuecomment-831505941 u can override Instant serialisation format with ObjectMapper.configOverride() method. As far as ObjectMapper is a bean, u can access it with Autowired field or method in java config class

Comment: I tried to move this part in my `jsonCustomizer` method, but does not make any sense. Is that wrong?`mapper.configOverride(Instant.class)               .setFormat(JsonFormat.Value.forPattern("yy-MM-dd HH:mm"));`

Comment: If so, how should I implement it with my class above?